# Printing out values between two indexes in for loop

Tags: java, oop

At the moment, I have made a method which gets the attributes from a number of players (from an ArrayList) between a starting index and an ending index. While this sounds easy enough, I get nothing printed out to the NetBeans console when I run the project. Here is the method code below:

```
/**
 * This overloaded method will print out the details of each player - 
 * that appear between "start" and "end" indexes of the players list.
 * 
 * @param players The list of players to be printed out.
 * @param start The list position of the first player.
 * @param end The list position of the last player.
 */
public void listNPlayers(ArrayList<Player> players, int start, int end)
{
    System.out.println(csvHeader + "\n");
    int i;
    //If start is greater than 0, and end is less than the total number of players in the list
    if(start > 0 && end < players.size())
    {

        for(i = 0; (i <= end && i >= start); i++)
        {
            System.out.println(players.get(i).toString());
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //if start is less than 0, tell the user to not use a negative value
        if(start < 0)
        {
            throw new ArithmeticException("You cannot use a negative index value for 'start'.");
        }
        //if end is greater than the size of the players list, tell the user that the value is too large.
        else if(end > players.size())
        {
            throw new ArithmeticException("Your 'end' value cannot be greater than the size of your 'players' list.");
        }
    }
}
```

I think the problem lies somewhere around the for-loop region, especially the condition in the loop. I haven't used the condition in this way before, but have been told it's legal. I have had someone else try and help me but still nothing is being printed out. This is probably a very small mistake I continually overlook.

If you want to run the project, you can clone my project files from GitHub at https://github.com/rattfieldnz/Java_Projects/tree/master/PCricketStats.

Thanks for any tips and suggestions :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may replace the line

```
for(i = 0; (i <= end && i >= start); i++)
```

with

```
for(i = start; i <= end; i++)
```

The first version does not iterate at all since `start>0` but `i=0` and thus the termination condition `i>=start` will stop the loop immediately.

Comment: Thats exactly what I should have used, I didn't know why I put the condition I had in the code. Thanks for the refresher :).

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you mean `start>=0`.
 Also your for-loop could be better as `for(i = start; i <= end ; i++)`

Answer (score 1):

You are using `if(start > 0 && end < players.size())` .

what if `start==0` ? It will never enter into if block and nothing will get printed.
So change it to `if(start >= 0 && end < players.size())` .

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - I realised this after further testing. Have implemented the change you suggested :).